# Can't find app in Play Store by name

Tags: android, search, google-play, publishing

I've published an app in Play Store week ago and there is a problem with search. I can't find it by searching my app by name in app list with same names, only if I type developer name, I can find it. How I can fix this? Thanks for answers.

Comment: Could you find your app eventually? What have you done for that?
Please accept one of the answers or post yours with what's worked for you.

Answer (score 23):

Google takes time to index their search engine, we have no control over that process and we don't know how long it takes.

Also you should do something related to **ASO** (App Store Optimization) to improve the visibility of your app (use **keywords** that your app relates to)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, only I couldn't find my app at all (by name / by quoted name / by developer name). For such cases, there is a way to check if your app is indexed at all.

Search for **pname: your.package.name** (replace *your.package.name*) at [play.google.com/store/apps](http://play.google.com/store/apps)

If you found it, it is correctly included in the search index.

A few tips I got from Play Store support to improve your app's visibility:

- Build a lasting and meaningful experience for your users
- Maintain and improve your app through regular updates
- Encourage users to provide feedback by leaving reviews and ratings for your app
- Provide great customer service by responding to your users and addressing issues

Answer (score 1):

One **short term** solution - Search app name (`<name>` in config.xml) within double quotes (for eg. "Foo Bar"). You would see your app, after the more popular/indexed apps with the same name.

For **long term**, customer/user friendly solution, you need to perform some ASO as specified by @TOP.

Answer (score 0):

[link to support team](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing?extra.IssueType=missing)

you can fill the form and they will check in 2 days

Comment: this does not provide an answer to this question